# TypeError: google.maps.latLng is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm am using Firefox to load my html file for GeoLocation. The problem is that I get these two messages in the console:

```
TypeError: google.maps.latLng is not a constructor index.html:26
error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Navigator</title>
</head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<script>

x = navigator.geolocation;

x.getCurrentPosition(success, failure);

function success(position) {

    // fetch coordinates

    var mylat = position.coords.latitude;
    var mylong = position.coords.longitude;

    // google api ready latitude and longitude string

    var coords = new google.maps.latLng(mylat, mylong);

    // setting up out google map

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: coords,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

// CREATING MAP

var map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

function failure() {
    $('#lat').html("<h3> No co-ordinates available!</h3>");
}
</script>

<body>
<!--map placeholder -->
<div id="map">

</div>

<div id="lat"></div>
<div id="long"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not even sure data from the Google Map API loaded correctly.
Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Typo again: LatLng() instead of latLng().

Comment: Guys, you both have high enough rep to know that Anto ought to post an answer and  Cyzanfar should accept it, to help others who read this question in future.

Answer (score 0):

**TypeError: google.maps.latLng is not a constructor**

```
 google.maps.LatLng
```

use instead of

```
google.maps.Latlng.
```

that's all, working perfectly in Google map.